# Why would identical NHibernate queries run an order of magnitude slower in a WinForm project than an MSTest unit test?

Tags: c#, winforms, fluent-nhibernate, mstest, select-n-plus-1

I have an app that is run as a service in production, but we do some manual testing with a simple GUI - practically nothing going on in it, it's just a wrapper with a textbox for input.

I recently changed my database schema and updated my mappings to match, and then the GUI suddenly worked very slowly on a trivial case.  After some logging and running it multiple times, it turned out the new bottleneck was this query:

```
public void Refresh()
{
  using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession()) 
  {
      _allFields = session.Query<FieldDefinition>().ToList();
  }
}
```

Repeatedly, it was taking 1:08 minutes for that one method (even though there's only about 300 FieldDefinitions in the database).  By this time I was tired of manually re-running the GUI, so I wrote a unit test that exercised the exact same case - but I couldn't reproduce the slowdown.

My test called the same top-level object that the GUI does with the same input. I would expect this to run in nearly identical amounts of time. But when run in Visual Studio with MSTest, that same query was taking less than two seconds. That's 1/30th the time. It was doing the exact same work, just significantly faster.

Things I checked to see if I could make them run the same:

- Both approaches produced the same number of SQL statements.
- It doesn't seem to be caused by the JITter (multiple runs of the GUI without restarting it, same time results over and over)
- Isolating it so that it used a brand new `ISessionFactory` for each `Refresh` had no effect
- Turning off logging (log4net) had no effect

Changing the query to eager-load a child *did* work... kind of: After applying the fix, the WinForms app is only as fast as the unit test *already was*.  The speed of the unit test did not significantly change (tenths of a second).

The old query was causing a `select n+1` issue: but the issue was present in both the Winform and MSTest runs.  Only the WinForm app saw a significant slowdown because of it.

How can I explain this? **Why would only the WinForm app suffer a massive slowdown during a Select N+1 query?**

Comment: "Both approaches produced the same number of SQL statements." -- Are the statements also the same, and do they take equally long to execute?

Comment: Do the run under the same SQL server (hardware/version)?

Comment: @hvd I haven't checked that, but I will.

Comment: @Schaliasos it's actually an Oracle 10G server, but yes, the same server. Same schema. Etc

Answer (score 0):

I'd say profile it, then you'll know.

Comment: Since I actually fixed the slowdown, and this is for work, I don't have a lot of license to spend time investigating this. I was hoping there was some conceptual subtlety I had missed, and that I wouldn't have to dig through the time and details of doing a proper profiling.